# Problems with Activity stack in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, stack-trace

I'm new to android development and I've developed a small app but I'm facing problems with linking different activities (i.e navigating between activities in a desired way).
I am sorry to ask these questions but I tried different solutions from google but none of them worked for me and I'm still not clear with these concepts.

Plz help

I have some questions:

1. How to delete activity at top of stack?
2. How to delete all activities from activity stack?
3. Intent(A.this,B.class) with (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) will not add activity B to  stack but what if I want to add activity A to stack?
4. Is there a way by which I can visualize contents of activity stack (that will help me to set appropriate flags while calling activities)?
5. I have an activity A (with 3 buttons) from which I call activity B where I get some operations done with user input and I want to come back to activity A but I want to show only 1 button out of those 3 how can I do this?
   (Problem I'm facing is the activity in A has 3 buttons so I want to relaunch it either by deleting it and making new intent OR making the same entry in stack to start again so that depending on conditions it will display 1 button)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope so you have solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for last qn:
Use startActivityForResult to start the Activity B and override onActivityForResult in Activity A. onActivityResult will be called When the Activity B is finished/exited.
You can set the visibility of the Buttons to GONE/INVISIBLE inside the onActivityResult.

Answer (score 5):

> How to delete activity at top of stack?

I have no idea what you think "delete" means with respect to activities. I have no idea what you mean by "top of stack" with respect to activities.

Assuming you mean "how do I destroy the foreground activity", the activity can call `finish()` on itself.

> How to delete all activities from activity stack?

You don't. You can call `startActivity()` with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to destroy all current activities on the stack, leaving you with the one you are now starting.

> Intent(A.this,B.class) with (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) will not add activity B to stack but what if I want to add activity A to stack?

Call `startActivity()` for A.

> Is there a way by which I can visualize contents of activity stack (that will help me to set appropriate flags while calling activities)?

You can sift through `adb shell dumpsys` to get this sort of information, but it is not especially friendly.

Your last question is incomprehensible to me, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answers they were really helpful to me!